# ionic Popup Modal data not loading issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

For a button click I have the following code. Once I pressed a button it suppose to load the ionic popup with some data populated on it.

```
    $scope.bettingGroupingOptions = bettingOption;
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: bettingOption.betName + ' ' + bettingOption.length + 'x',
        scope: $scope,
        templateUrl: 'templates/grouping_combo_selections.html'
    });
    alertPopup.then(function(res, bettingOption) {
        console.log(bettingOption);
        //console.log("BETTING AMILA : " + bettingOption);
        //console.log("DOUBLE BETNAMES : " +$scope.doubleBetNames);
        //console.log("BET NAME : " + $scope.bettingDoubleOption.betName);
        // console.log("DOUBLE BETNAMES ALL : " +$scope.doubleBetNames.betName);
        //console.log("Multiflier : " +bettingDoubleOption.multiplier);
    });
```

Popup gets loaded but unfortunately data is not there. Can anyone please help me to fix this. Data is in this variable "$scope.bettingGroupingOptions" But in the popup it is not reflecting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no 2nd args in this promise success function, putting  `bettingOption` there makes this variable undefined :

```
$scope.bettingGroupingOptions = bettingOption;
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: bettingOption.betName + ' ' + bettingOption.length + 'x',
        scope: $scope,
        templateUrl: 'templates/grouping_combo_selections.html'
    });
});
alertPopup.then(function(res) {
    console.log(bettingOption);
});
```